# Attributes with no android namespaces on xml's

Tags: android, xml

I'm just a beginner in android and studying how to create styles and themes.
I found this xml here:

[Material Log In Demo](https://github.com/sourcey/materiallogindemo/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml)

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/iron</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/iron</item>

    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/iron</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

What I'm confused about is why some `name` attributes of `<item>` directives have no `android` namespace on them, while others have? Like the `colorButtonNormal` and `android:colorButtonNormal`. Can someone explain when/why they are used please?

Answer (score 0):

Referring the android [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) and finding the name attribute as "Required". Android resources uses XML which implies they need to use XML Schema. If they are using any namespace => they don't want any conflicts with the name. Hope this helps
For reference:
A "Schema" is what is required to allow the acceptance (or creation) of XML documents with a standardized element name and hierarchy structure.

Answer (score 0):

afaik, we need to use `android:propertyName` to override the properties of specific style based on the API Level. For example, in property name of `value/styles.xml` you may need to use:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    ...
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

But in `values-v14/styles.xml` you need to use:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    ...
    <item name="background">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Here the `<item name="android:background">` and `<item name="background">` has the same meaning. Just a different naming convention for the specific API Level.

Please be noted that the example is just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: I'll try to find the related documentation and include it here. For now, the answer only based on my experience.